# Python: How to find certain characters in nested list and return indexes

Tags: python

I am after a way to return a a tuple list of indexes of where these certain characters are.

For example, I want to know where in my nested list that I have blank spaces (" ").

Say I have this:

```
board = [
        ["a", " ", " "],
        [" ", "x", " "],
        [" ", "b", " "]
    ]
```

and my function will be:

```
def empty_squares(board):
"""Return a list of the empty squares in the board, each as
   a (row, column) tuple"""
```

So if I run the function it would return `[(0,1), (0,2), (1,0), (1,2), (2,0), (2,2)]`.

I'm just not sure how to do this for nested lists.

Thank you!

Comment: Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you've tried and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer! See also: [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can loop over the board and use enumerate to keep track of the indexes.

```
l = []

for indexa, e in enumerate(board):
    for indexb, c in enumerate(e):
        if c == ' ':
            l.append((indexa, indexb))
```

Or simply with a list comprehension:

```
l = [(indexa, indexb) for indexb, c in enumerate(e) for indexa, e in enumerate(board) if c == ' ']
```

Both will output:

```
[(0, 1), (0, 2), (1, 0), (1, 2), (2, 0), (2, 2)]
```

Comment: Thank you! I forgot about enumerate and what it does. :)

Answer (score 2):

Maybe with enumerate?

```py
board = [
        ["a", " ", " "],
        [" ", "x", " "],
        [" ", "b", " "]
    ]

def empty_squares(board, symbol):
    """
    Return a list of the empty squares in the board, each as
    a (row, column) tuple
    """
    empty = []
    for row, sublist in enumerate(board):
        for column, item in enumerate(sublist):
            if item == symbol:
                empty.append((row, column))
    return empty

>>> empty_squares(board, ' ')
[(0, 1), (0, 2), (1, 0), (1, 2), (2, 0), (2, 2)]
```

Comment: Thanks! This helped. I totally forgot about enumerate and what it could do. :)

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is probably to use `numpy.where()`.

```
import numpy as np


board = [
    ["a", " ", " "],
    [" ", "x", " "],
    [" ", "b", " "]
]

idxs = [(i, j) for i, j in zip(*np.where(np.array(board) == ' '))]
print(idxs)
```

Comment: Thank you. :) Unfortunately we can't use numpy at the moment for this.